# The extension of Fourier transform from $L^1\cap L^2$ to $L^2$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

In Grafakos's book, in order to the define Fourier transform on $L^2$, he claims that the Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^1\cap L^2$. Since Fourier transform is an isometry, thus $\hat{f}\in L^2$. However, I couldn't figure out why $\hat{f}\in L^1$.

Comment: Actually some of the nicest functions you can think of don't have their Fourier transform in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. A good exercise is to show that there is a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{f}\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. One instance where $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is when $f$ is such that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, it isn't. Here, "on" doesn't mean what it usually means, that is one space to itself, but rather that it is an $L^2$ isometry from $L^1\cap L^2$ to $L^2$. A good example is the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$. Its Fourier transform has finite $L^2$ norm, but it is not Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is the function $\hat{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
\hat{f}(\xi):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\,dx
$$

Here's a way to see that $f:=\chi_{[-1,1]}$ (which is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is such that $\hat{f}\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose the contrary. Then the Inversion Theorem would apply and we would have
$$
\hat{\hat{f}}(-x)=2\pi f(x)
$$
at every point where $f$ is continuous, so (since $f$ is pair)
$$
\hat{\hat{f}}(x)=2\pi\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)
$$
for all $x\neq1,-1$. So $\hat{\hat{f}}$ would be continuous (since it would be the FT of $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ by hypothesis) and such that
$$
\hat{\hat{f}}=\begin{cases}2\pi&&|x|<1\\0&&|x|>1\end{cases}
$$
This is impossible, so $\hat{f}\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: This approach is really good for showing that the abstract Fourier transform of the characteristic function of an open set isn't in $L^1$. Great argument!

Comment: @Cameron Williams I have no merit! This argument was shown to me when I took a class dealing with Fourier analysis.